# google health api

Tags: android

in my app i want to show the data of google health data for a particular account .how can i 
proceed.any suggetion.where can i get the jar of the api

Answer (score 1):

Google health api is to be used with Google Data api, which works on android. Check out the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/health/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java.html).

And here is google api [android java client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/)